# Textbox disappears when linkbutton is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem. I'm trying to make some panels, and in these panels I would like to have some linkbuttons, when the user click a linkbutton of a panel a textbox will appear in that panel, when I click in another linkbutton the textboxes of that panel also appear without problem but when I click in the other linkbutton the texboxes created in the previous panel disappears.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        Label myLabel1;
        Label myLabel2;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myLabel1 = new Label();
            myLabel2 = new Label();
            Panel1.Controls.Add(myLabel1);
            Panel2.Controls.Add(myLabel2);
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                //Remove the session when first time page loads.
                Session.Remove("clicks");
                Session.Remove("clicks2");
            }

        }

        protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rowCount = 0;
            //initialize a session.
            rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);
            rowCount++;
            //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
            Session["clicks"] = rowCount;
            //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
                TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
                //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
                Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);

            }
            myLabel1.Text = rowCount + "";

        }

        protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int rowCount2 = 0;
            //initialize a session.
            rowCount2 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks2"]);
            rowCount2++;
            //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
            Session["clicks2"] = rowCount2;
            //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount2; i++)
            {

                TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
                TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
                //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
                Panel2.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);

            }
            myLabel2.Text = rowCount2 + "";
        }
    }
```

And here is the other part:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p>
        Part I</p>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="53px">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Add to 1</asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="51px">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Add to 2</asp:LinkButton>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Panel>
</form>
```

Comment: You have to rebuild dynamic controls on every postback. So even when LinkButton2 is clicked you have to run code from LinkButton1 for textboxes to exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the text boxes are dynamically created, when the page loads everything needs to be re-built, but the code you posted only re-builds the text boxes for one of the panels when the particular link button for that panel is being clicked. However, your code is just building the one panel again, because that is all that your click event handlers for the link buttons are telling it to do.

I suggest combining the logic into a single method that does the building and then each link button click event handler can update its own count and pass it to the method, like this:

```
private void BuildTextBoxes(int rowCount1, int rowCount2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
        TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
        //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);
    }

    myLabel1.Text = rowCount + "";

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount2; i++)
    {
        TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
        TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
        //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
        Panel2.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);
    }

    myLabel2.Text = rowCount2 + "";
}
```

Now in your link button click event handlers, you will need to update the one count, but pass both to the method, like this:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = 0;
    //initialize a session.
    rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);
    rowCount++;
    //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
    Session["clicks"] = rowCount;

    BuildTextBoxes(rowCount, Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks2"]));
}

protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount2 = 0;
    //initialize a session.
    rowCount2 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks2"]);
    rowCount2++;
    //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
    Session["clicks2"] = rowCount2;

    BuildTextBoxes(Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks1"]), rowCount2));
}
```

Now, whether you click the first or second link button, all of the text boxes will be recreated; with only the particular link button incrementing the number of rows.

Comment: Your code is working good but when I click on linkbutton2 the textboxes from Panel1 disappear, it looks like the rowCounter1 is getting cero when I click on it. But when I click on the linkbutton1 the counter gets the real value and the textboxes from Panel2 stay. Why do you think this is happening? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I realized now, it was because in linkbutton2_click says clicks1 and it's just click... Thank you so much. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a post-back to the server following the click on the link an entirely new HTML page is generated and returned to the client. In the click event handler in your code you are adding additional controls to the ones in your aspx markup. These are then included in the HTML returned to the client. But the server is state-less and will not remember that you added these the next time there is a request from the client. You will need to add them again every time there is a post-back.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to move your logic to add the text boxes into a separate method and then call it with the appropriate values in your click.

Something like this:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]) + 1;
    Session["clicks"] = rowCount;
    int rowCount2 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks2"]) + 1;
    Session["clicks2"] = rowCount2;
    AddTextBoxes(rowCount, Panel1, myLabel1);
    AddTextBoxes(rowCount2, Panel2, myLabel2);
}

protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]) + 1;
    Session["clicks"] = rowCount;
    int rowCount2 = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks2"]) + 1;
    Session["clicks2"] = rowCount2;
    AddTextBoxes(rowCount, Panel1, myLabel1);
    AddTextBoxes(rowCount2, Panel2, myLabel2);
}

protected void AddTextBoxes(int numberToAdd, Panel panel, Label label)
{
    //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
    numberToAdd = rowCount;
    //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();
        TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();
        //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
        panel.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);

    }
    label.Text = rowCount + "";
}
```